# How is polygamy handled policy wise in democratic countries where it is legal?

Tags: policy, marriage

First question: are there any democratic ("somewhat" democratic like Russia counts... Saudi Arabia or any other Islamic theocracy does not) countries where polygamy is not fully illegal the way it is in USA?

Second, real, question: if such countries exist, how do the handle polygamy policy wise?

What I mean is, are there standard laws on how inheritance works in absence of a will? What are the default rules in terms of medical treatment if multiple spouses have different opinion and patient is not capable to decide? What accounting principles govern taxes?

Comment: it may be better placed at law.se

Comment: Rather broad -- Perhaps you could do the research to find such a country (do you consider Indonesia to be democratic?)  The standard laws in most countries that allow polygamy are sharia. So you can google the sharia laws on marriage.

Comment: @JamesK - that's basically what I was driving at with "democratic" thing, just rather less artfully. I want laws that deal with polygamy without being explicitly Sharia-polygamy-rules based.

Comment: Does Iran count as “somewhat” democratic, or as a theocracy? BTW, there’s a smidgen of handling of plural marriage by the Australian government.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - Iran is (and its laws are Sharia based)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In South Africa polygamy via customary marriages is [legal](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Recognition_of_Customary_Marriages_Act,_1998#s7) but for every spouse after the first an explicit agreement of how the property rights work needs to be made and approved by a court.